# Windows Service .NET Core REST API

Tags: c#, rest, .net-core, windows-services, port

I am trying to create a Windows Service using the .NET Core Web API template to respond to REST requests.

I have already managed to get a service up and running following these instructions (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio). My issue is that I don't know how to have my Windows Service listen on a port for POST requests to its controllers.

I've looked through some other StackOverflow solutions but from what I've seen they don't address this issue with the .NET Core Web API template.

I would like to send a request to some endpoint, say 'POST localhost:5000/api/endpoint' and have my Windows Service perform some task and return a status code (ie. 2xx, 4xx, 5xx).

Comment: I'm curious, what's the reasoning for having a windows service behave in this manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is `UseUrls` extension method which allows you to set up port.

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.UseUrls("http://*:5000")
.UseStartup<Startup>();
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.hostingabstractionswebhostbuilderextensions.useurls?view=aspnetcore-2.2